# Magento Newsletter Subscription Confirmation NOT sent

Tags: magento-1.7, email, newsletter

I've noticed that when entering an email in the `newsletter subscription` field on my website for `newsletter confirmation`, the customers do not receive subscription confirmation in their emails.

In the `System  >  Configuration > Newsletter > Need to confirm **(YES)**`

Even though it says YES, there are no  emails sent to customers that asks customers to re-confirm whether they actually want to sign up for newsletter. Its also called "Double-Confirmation"

Please help me out.

Many thanks!

Comment: Do any emails get set from your server?

Comment: Could you please clarify ? 
If I understood correctly, I have several emails created on the server through cPanel. usually they are: contact@website.com or newsletter@website.com

Comment: Any help ? Can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Don't need to install extension and make load on site.
go to

> \app\locale\en_US\template\email\newsletter_subscr_success.html

delete full page content & from now you don't get any mail on news later subscription.

Comment: Can you please tell me when newsletter status change from unsubscribe to subscribe at that time mail will be send to that user?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check other configurations of newsletter too.

```
 System > Configuration > Newsletter
```

There is a field called `Allow Guest Subscription`. If it is set to `No`, then Magento will not send newsletter to guest users. Only users who are singed in your site will get newsletter confirmation email when they requetst. Most probably this would be the cause.

[*This answer is a part of #mageStackDay. It is an event conducted by Magento Community members as part of increasing the question-answer ratio. For more information http://www.magestackday.com/*]